# iPad and Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, ipad

We have Exchange 2003 and both OWA and OMA working over HTTPS. I don't have a device to test OMA with but at least I can access it with a browser, even though I get a message saying that it's an unsupported device.

We have a user with an iPad that we're trying to get connected to Exchange. Although there's no problem using IMAP the MAPI connection just will not work. As this is only a single user I would normally be inclined to tell her to just settle for IMAP. Unfortunately, I have been informed that the company owner and managing director both intend to get iPads, so this will become a BIG problem very soon.

Is there some special trick to getting the iPad to connect to Exchange? I've followed a bunch of articles found on the Internet but am getting nowhere. Perhaps, like Mac Snow Leopard's Mail, it really only works with Exchange 2007 onwards but I've found no mention of that.

Have any of you managed to do this? If so, can you please share the procedure used.

Comment: Any reason your not using Exchange 2003 Activesync to get push mail functionality? (assuming you have SP2 installed)

Comment: @Sam, is it a requirement for the iPad? I have no other reason for it.

Comment: No, you don't have to use it, I just find that it's much easier to get working, and you have the advantage of getting push mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sam has stated, you should be looking into configuring [RPC over HTTP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833401) on the Exchange server so that you can utilize ActiveSync. OMA is only a browser based "view" of the mailbox and is not a connection method.

Comment: In Exchange 2003, RPC over HTTP and activesync are 2 different things. You can setup activesync to allow mobile devices to pull mail over the air. RPC over HTTP allows you to connect your Outlook client to Exchange using http, and just enabling that won't really help you here. That said, in later versions of Exchange it's all been lumped together.

Comment: My bad, I'm so used to setting up RPC over HTTP on devices and not ActiveSync. Do any current devices even have an ActiveSync option?